# Getting input from the console efficiently

Tags: java

I'm working on uva 00787

(a problem from website uva online judge: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=9&page=show_problem&problem=728)

that takes a list of numbers and finds the sub-sequence of the list that yields the largest product. But actually, the program just only displays the largest product, not actually the sub-sequence, or the start and end indices of it.

I suppose since I've been suggested to use java's BigInteger to contain a very large number, potentially a hundred numbers in the list, each of which could be 5 digits long, therefore the maximum value could be 99999^100 (very large!!). With that knowledge in mind, it makes sense to use BigInteger.

Now, my question is much simpler. My main preference is C++, and I have to use more consideration to the language of java when writing code, and I thought there is probably a more efficient way of doing simple parsing than what I have done. I'm basically using the Scanner class and String class, and then using string parsing to get the values I want from a line of text. Here's what I do (as a simple example):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int next;
    String number = scanner.nextLine();
    while(!number.isEmpty())
    {
        do
        {
            next = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, number.indexOf(' ')));
            number = number.substring(number.indexOf(' ') + 1, number.length());
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(next));
        }while(!number.equals("-999999"));
        System.out.println(number);
        number = scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

What's happening here is, I'm getting a line from the console, and using "-999999" as a sentinel value. The loop parses every integer from the list, and gives it's value on the console. Once "-999999" is detected, then the loop ends. Then, the program waits for another line, which kicks it back into the loop looking for the sentinel value of "-999999", unless the next line is empty as a result of the user just pressing the enter key. Then the outer loop terminates, and so too does the program.

I don't particularly like this solution, but I can't think of a better way. It's hard to describe why I don't like it. Perhaps it's just because I'm getting the feeling that it's more complicated than need be.

Thanks for whatever guidance can be provided,

Brent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this way:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
List<Integer> list;

while(sc.hasNext()) { // until EOF
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        if(n == -999999)
            break;
        list.add(n);
    }
    System.out.println(list);
    // Your list of numbers are ready. Do whatever you need.
}
```

Comment: That kinda works...

But then I'm stuck in an infinite loop. At least in NetBeans Ide 8.1 I am.
The problem is, hasNext() keeps asking me for input. I can't just terminate by pressing enter on no input. This is why I have to use sc.nextLine() which allows me to load a string as "", which I then check its contents, and this is what gets me out of the loop (when the string is set to "").

Comment: use eof to terminate, such as ctr+d, ctr+z etc.

Comment: However, if I submit a problem like this to uva online judge, it may end up as a TLE (time limit exceeded) because there won't be any input such as ctrl+c, etc.

Comment: That last comment I added:

"However, if I submit a problem like this to uva online judge, it may end up as a TLE (time limit exceeded) because there won't be any input such as ctrl+c, etc."

Should have made me question further. I didn't realize it until now, that is exactly how uva online judge expects the input. It will give the eof to terminate at the end of it's input, therefore, sc.hasNext() from your answer WAS totally sufficient in this case.

Should have realized it sooner.

Thanks Shahid.